# CakePHP page with no headers/footers

Tags: cakephp, download, blob

In a download page for a blob from a database, how would I make it so that no other output is sent? Right now it's sending the header, debug info, and a footer. How do I make it so that none of that is sent, just for that view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create an clear layout (e.g. `empty.ctp` ) in you layouts folder, only with

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout ?>
```

and then in you action where you're getting your blob data use that layout

```
$this->layout = 'empty.ctp';
```

and also to disable debugging, in your controllers use

```
Configure::write('debug',0);
```

if you're unable to create new layout you could try this.

```
$this->layout = null;
$this->render("view_name");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using this to download files, you should use the `Media` view in cakePHP

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1094/Media-Views

```
    $this->view = 'Media';
    $params = array(
          'id' => 'example.zip',
          'name' => 'example',
          'download' => true,
          'extension' => 'zip',  // must be lower case
          'path' => APP . 'files' . DS   // don't forget terminal 'DS'
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

**CakePhp 2.3 users :**

- use [Sending files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file) from *the Book*

**CakePhp 2.x users :**

- use '$this->viewClass' instead of '$this->view'

copy-paste ready full solution, right in any controller file:

```
<?php

public function download($file) {

    $fsTarget = APP.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.'files'.DS.$file; // files located in 'files' folder under webroot
    if (false == file_exists($fsTarget)){
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid file'));
    }

    $pathinfo = pathinfo($fsTarget);

    $this->viewClass = 'Media';

    $params = array(
          'id' => $file,
          'name' => $pathinfo['filename'], // without extension
          'download' => true,
          'extension' => $pathinfo['extension'],  // must be lower case
          'path' => dirname($fsTarget) . DS // don't forget terminal 'DS'
   );
   $this->set($params);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Media view is deprecated - in 2.x one should use the response class for these things as documented.

Comment: Hi mark, I will update the answer. Even if 2.3 is not even released on the homepage yet. As for my code, this method was written looong before :)

Comment: 2.x != 2.3 (2.x = 2.0/2.1/2.2/2.3). and even in 2.0 you could already use the response class for this.